# How to parse strict *.xlsx file in Java

Tags: apache-poi, openxml, import-from-excel

I need to parse data from xlsx file. Currently I'm using Jakarta-POI (v. 3.11) to do that. It handles fine some xlsx but not all. I noticed that the files that are not parsed properly are "strict xlsx" files saved with Office 2013. To be more exact this files are compliant with ISO29500 not ECMA-376 the difference is that in ISO29500 file there are relationships with type:

> http://purl.oclc.org/ooxml/officeDocument/relationships/officeDocument

and Jakarta-POI is looking for:

> String CORE_DOCUMENT =
>   "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument"

Is there a way to make Jakarta-POI read this files?

Comment: I believe it's the other way around, that ISO 29500 uses the openxmlformats.org namespaces and ECMA-376 uses the purl.oclc.org namespaces. Not that it matters to the core of your question :)  I take it that opening with Excel and saving is not an option?

Comment: Do you mean [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)? There hasn't been a Jakarta POI in many many years...

Comment: There's an [Apache POI bug for this](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57699) which you might want to follow and/or help with!

Comment: Thanks for response. I was able to create workaround. On https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/master/src/Framework/NamespaceIdMap.cs there is a list of translation for relationship and namespaces. So what I do right now is read files from xlsx zip and do all required substitutions and then read it with ApachePOI. The clean fix would be to support all listed aliases.

Comment: FWIW, the list of namespaces @jethro mentioned is available at [https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/blob/master/src/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/Framework/NamespaceIdMap.cs]

Answer (score 3):

[OOXML Strict Converter for Office 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38828) may help if you need to resave the docs using an older format.

Some of the purl namespaces are listed on http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/PyXB-1.2.2/bundles.html (Jethro's link above appears to no longer work).

The up to date XML schema files can be found at:
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm

Comment: I am using a slightly modified version of @PJFanning's ooxml-strict-converter [https://github.com/pjfanning/ooxml-strict-converter] to check for and convert the strict files before reading them with POI.